# Is there a way to add a delay and fade in form the right to a sticky button?

Tags: html, css

I have written this code:

```
.your-button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -1%;
  bottom: -1%; 
  width: 3.2rem; 
}
```

But was hoping to add a delay so that it appears half way down the page with a motion effect to fade in from the right.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

CSS fade in from right.  Hopefully you can get enough from this example to apply it to your situation.

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -70px;
  transition: left .5s, opacity 1s;
}

div:hover .btn {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hover here
  <button class="btn fade" type="button">Hello</button>
</div>
```